# Java update a File atomically

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'am using FFmpeg application to stream live video with a text stored in a file. The problem is that I must update the file with new data and those data must be shown in video stream.

In Java have done a simple script in a loop which write some string in /tmp/ folder like this:

```
public class FileSaverTS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

       Date d = null;
       String s= "";
        try {
            while (true) {
                d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                s = df.format(d);
                System.out.println("File Saver: " + df.format(d));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("podatki.txt", "UTF-8");
                out.write("Test: " + s);
                out.close();
                Thread.sleep(1000);


            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSaverTS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSaverTS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSaverTS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSaverTS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

When I run FFmpeg application I got this kind of error: [image]

How to write a file atomically with Java? 
from FFmpeg manual: ( Be sure to update it atomically, or it may be read partially, or even fail)

Comment: This depends on the file format, and in som cases requires cooperation from all potential readers of the file.

Comment: File is a text file..